# Creating an upstart service for dumping and uploading a mysql database on shutdown

Tags: scripts, shutdown, upstart

I am running Ubuntu Server 14.04 LTS x64. I have two KVM guests. One is a file server and another runs mysql server.

I have a script that I run on the file server. The script connects via ssh to the guest that runs mysql server, dumps a mysql database and uploads it to another remote server. The script works as expected. Now I want to make this script to run at shutdown.

I have read about upstart and tried to make a service to accomplish this. I created my init file (/etc/init/dotproject_backup.conf) with this content:

```
# dotproject_backup
# This service makes a dump and rsync of a dotproject mysql database prior to shutdown.

description "dotproject backup"
author "Rodrigo Martinho"

start on startup
stop on runlevel [016]

pre-stop script
exec /home/user/script.sh
end script
```

In this example I also put runlevel 6 so I can test it on reboot. I may change that after all works. On reboot, the system isn't waiting for the script to run. In fact it seems the script isn't running at all, as I can see on the log file (/var/log/upstart/dotproject_backup).

I tried some other setups where the script was started, but shutdown completed before the dump was uploaded:

```
# dotproject_backup
# This service makes a dump and rsync of a dotproject mysql database prior to shutdown.

description "dotproject backup"
author "Rodrigo Martinho"

start on runlevel [016] or stopping dbus or deconfiguring-networking

script
exec /home/user/script.sh
end script
```

In this setup I can see on log file that the script was started, but it was killed when file was being uploaded.

I read on another post here that the correct way of accomplishing this is changing the start condition, so script is run before the reboot process is started:

```
# dotproject_backup
# This service makes a dump and rsync of a dotproject mysql database prior to shutdown.

description "dotproject backup"
author "Rodrigo Martinho"

start on starting rc RUNLEVEL=[016]

script
exec /home/user/script.sh
end script
```

But in this example again the shutdown completed before the script.

So, my questions are:

- Should I make the service start or stop when runlevel changes for shutdown or reboot?
- How should I make the shutdown to wait until the script is complete?
- Would it be a better approach to run my script as a pre-stop inside another service?

Thanks in advance for any help,

Rodrigo Martinho.

Comment: I suppose running the script on startup instead of on shutdown is not an option?

Comment: No, it isn't an option, because what I need is the latest mysql dump so I can import it on the remote server and continue to use dotproject when the first server is down, for instance, due to lack of energy. When the first server is running I don't need to use the remote one.

Comment: Anyone could help with this?